# Proof about finite dimensional vector spaces over fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

Prove that every finite dimensional vector space $V $of dimension $n$ over a field $F$ is isomorphic to the vector space $F^n$.

Okay, lot's of stuff here. I think most of the reason I can not do this one is because I don't have a clear understanding of everything going on here.

As far as I know, $F^n$ is the set of all $n$-tuples of $F$, or

$F^n$ = $\{(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) | a_i \in F\}$

I have many questions about the rest, though. is $V$ finite ONLY when viewed as a vector space over $F$? What does it really mean for $V$ to be viewed as a vector space over $F$?

To approach this problem, I need to find an isomorphism between V and $F^n$ but it sure helps to know the stuff I posted above to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about $F^n$; that's exactly what it means.  The key here is that $V$ is finite dimensional; so here's where you should start:

*What does it mean for a vector-space $V$ to be $n$-dimensional?*

Comment: We need $n$ linearly independent vectors of $V$ to form a basis for $V$.

Comment: Good.  Now, supposing that $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, construct an isomorphism from $V$ to $F^n$, and prove that it is indeed an isomorphism of vector spaces.

Comment: In particular, if $\phi$ is such a map, we can take 
$$
\phi(v_k) = (\overbrace{0,\dots,0}^{k-1},1,0,\dots,0)
$$

Comment: I think I see what is going on. so $v_1$ will map to the first space in the n-tuple, or $(1,0,0,...,0)$, $v_2$ will map to $(0,1,0,...,0$ etc.

Comment: @terribleatmath That's right.  The meat of the proof is showing that this defines an isomorphism of the two vector spaces.

Comment: thanks @Omnomnomnom! You've got a silly name but you're a smart and helpful guy!

Comment: do you have a general definition for your function (not just basis vectors?) im trying to think of how to show injectivity and surjectivity and that would help.

Comment: @terribleatmath First of all, I realize that this proof is a bit easier if you make the isomorphism go in the opposite direction.  That is, take
$$
\phi(\overbrace{0,\dots,0}^{k-1},1,0,\dots,0) = v_k
$$
Of course, if $\phi$ is an isomorphism then so is its inverse, but this way seems smoother.
Now, if you know what $\phi(1,0,0,\dots)$ is and what $\phi(0,1,0,\dots)$ is, what does $\phi(2,3,0,\dots,)$ need to be?  Use the definition of a homomorphism of vector spaces.  Now, for injection/surjection, you'll need the definition of a basis.

Comment: Remember, for $\phi$ to be a vector-space (or module) homomorphism, we must have
$$
\phi(a_1v_1 + a_2 v_2) = a_1\phi(v_1) + a_2\phi(v_2)
$$
For any scalars $a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb{F}$ and vectors $v_1,v_2 \in V$.

Comment: Thanks again. is the definition of a homomorphism of vector spaces any different than a homomorphism of rings? Judging by your most recent comment, no.

Comment: @terribleatmath similar, but different; notice how $a_1$ simply comes out in front, and note that $\phi(a_1)$ might have no meaning.

Comment: good point, because $a_1$ is an element of $F$ and $\phi$ is a function from $F^n$. I will look up the concrete definition online, i dont think my book has it.

Comment: @terribleatmath see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map).  Your book should have it if it defines a vector space or a module.

Comment: Oh, so a homomorphism of vector spaces is just a linear function! that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Om, i completed my proof for this. I accepted your answer to thank you for all your help.

Comment: @terribleatmath No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

For a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$, this means that the scalar multiplication of elements of $V$ also lie in $V$ (satisfying the vector space axioms).

To see that it matters what field a vector space is over, take $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over itself.  This is pretty trivial of an example.  However, taking $V=\mathbb{R}$ and the field as $\mathbb{Q}$ gives a wildly different vector space.

As far as establishing an isomorphism, here's a hint: Select a basis for $V$.

Comment: each individual piece of each $n$-tuple is an element of $V$, right?

Comment: No, each individual piece of an $n$-tuple is an element of the field.  The idea is that you set up a correspondence between a set of vectors in $V$ and a set of $n$-tuples in $\FF^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of $V$ being a finite dimensional vector space over $F$ is that it is spanned by a finite amount of elements. Thus it is finite iff $F$ is finite. Specifically, if $V$ is an $n$-dimensional $F$-space, then $V$ is of the form $\{\alpha_1e_1+\ldots+\alpha_ne_n\,\,|\,\,\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in F\}$, where $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ are the spanning elements. Note that the vector space axioms imply that $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is an abelian group. Can you now think of a possible homomorphism from $V$ to $F^n$?

Comment: I can't right off the bat but I think this is starting to come together, it at least makes intuitive sense why $F^n$ and $V$ are isomorphic, since $V$ is all linear combinations of elements of $F$ with vectors from $V$ and $F^n$ is all n-tuples of $F$, we can generate every element of $F^n$ from those linear combinations.

Comment: Exactly. Or maybe easier is the other way around. Given a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ every element in $V$ is fixed by the coefficients before the basis elements. Thus every element in $V$ is fixed by a combination of $n$ elements in $F$, so maybe a certain element in $F^n$?

Comment: Check my comment on Omnom's answer I think im figuring it out :)